# Force api connect HTTP not HTTPS

Tags: htaccess, https

I have a problem with forcing http for my api call

external program (cant edit it) connects with api using http. 
curently i have enabled https and api doesnt connect with external server anymore.

in magento i set base url and secure url as https:// - cant connect

when i set base url: http and secure url https - connection is fine, but problem with ssl as on the website i get unsecured content.

could you help me with that?

i guess good htacces rule should work but noting works for me.

this is how my rewrite looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
```

any sugestions how to force http for api only?